# When i turn off the DEBUG mode in settings.py it returns a bad request(400)

Tags: python-3.x, django

[I see this when i turn off Debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Uze.png)

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
'localhost:8000',
]
```

How am i going to fix this?

Comment: There is no need to put the `8000` port. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` only uses addresses (e.g IP). Change it to `.localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: It still shows the ```bad request (400)``` i just did as you said

Comment: You can also use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` but it's less secure.

Comment: i don't know what's wrong with my files. When i turn off the ```DEBUG``` and then put the ```ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']``` Then the whole bootstrap in it goes off. Is it safe to publish django applications with ```DEBUG=True```?

Comment: `Never deploy a site into production with DEBUG turned on.` and  

`Finally, if DEBUG is False, you also need to properly set the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting. Failing to do so will result in all requests being returned as “Bad Request (400)”.`
 - Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG

Comment: How do i set the hosts for localhost and the domain name??. It gives an error